# Geolocation: ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'lat' of null

Tags: angular, typescript, geolocation, typeerror, angular9

**Introduction**

I'm working on an Angular application where I want to get the current position of the user and save the longtitude and altitude in two properties `lng` and `lat`, yet this doesn't seem to work and no matter what I try; I keep on getting the error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'lat' of null`

**TypeScript code (the relevant part)**

```
  lat : any;
  lng : any;

  constructor() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.setValues);
    }
   }

  setValues(values) {
    this.lat = values?.coords?.latitude
    this.lng = values?.coords?.longitude;
  }
```

The error is thrown in the first line of setValues

**The (relevant part of the) JSON object that is returned by getCurrentPosition**

```
{
  coords:
  {
    latitude: 27.380583,
    longitude: 33.631839
  }
}
```

**What I tried**

- The JSON is well received and I can print it, also its subobjects. I can even bind it to a local variable within the setValues method. I also tried binding that local variable to the properties but that caused the same error.
- Changing `lat: any` to `lat: number` or adding `public` in front of it.
- Getting rid of the null operators in the setValues method.
- Putting the code in the ngOnInit method.

All of these tries caused the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is to do with what `this` refers to in different scopes. It only refers to the outer scope (the component in this case) when you use an arrow function. Otherwise `this` refers to the funtion itself.

You can see it in action for yourself by setting up the following test:

```js
ngOnInit() {

  // 1. delegate function
  this.getValues(this.setValues);

  // 2. function() { }
  this.getValues(function(values) {
    console.log(this);
  });

  // 3. arrow function
  this.getValues(values => this.setValues(values));
}

getValues(callback: (values) => void) {
  callback({
    lat: 1,
    long: 2
  });
}

setValues(values) {
  console.log(this);
}
```

This shows 3 different ways of passing a function in as a callback. 1. and 2. will log `undefined` to the console. 3. will log the containing class (`AppComponent` in my demo).

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c8eypx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what the problem is, but it has to do with the scope and by making an anonymous callback function it seems to work fine.

```
  constructor() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((values) => { 
        this.lat = values?.coords?.latitude
        this.lng = values?.coords?.longitude;
      });
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your function anonymous:

```
  setValues = (values) => {
    this.lat = values?.coords?.latitude
    this.lng = values?.coords?.longitude;
  }
```